# turtles-own variable to global variable on NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I am creating a NetLogo model to simulate the use of appliances in a household and I've got 2 turtles: people & appliances. I have declared a `peoples-own` for `appliances_hit` and `appliances-own` for `times_used`.

I want to be able to calculate the total `times_used` from ALL of the appliances ie. `times_used` of `(appliance1 + appliance2 + ... appliance6`) I will use that total to plot a graph by performing some calculations to show the usage data.

I would highly appreciate any sort of help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [sum command](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/sum.html) and it will return the total of `time_used` for all appliances. It will be like this:

```
sum [time_used] of appliances
```